# Welche Präpositionen folgen auf "Portierung" (Softwareportierung)?

Tags: preposition

Ich bin gerade über einen Titel gestolpert: "Portierung eines Verfahrens von Matlab zu C++ in Qt". Mein Sprachgefühl würde in dieser Situation lieber "Portierung von ... nach ..." verwenden. Ich habe auch schon Formulierungen der Form "Portierung von Windows auf Linux" gesehen, die ich gut nachvollziehen kann.

Meine Frage lautet: In welchen Situationen werden die folgenden Präpositionen verwendet?

- Portierung von ... zu ...
- Portierung von ... auf ...
- Portierung von ... nach ...

Comment: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Portierung+zu%2CPortierung+auf%2CPortierung+nach&year_start=1900&year_end=2013&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: @bummi Aber http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=portieren+zu%2C+portieren+auf%2C+portieren+nach&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: @em1: Wenn du dir die Texte mit "portieren zu" genauer anguckst, ist in den älteren Texten meist die Rede von Portieren (Vorhänge) und in den neueren Texten zusätzlich Bruchstücke wie "portieren zu können" und "portieren zu müssen".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Portierung ist ein relativ neuer Fachbegriff der EDV, für den es naturgemäß noch keine verbindlichen Regeln gibt (zur [Begriffsabgrenzung siehe auch Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Migration_%28Informationstechnik%29#Begriffsabgrenzung)).

---

### nach

Nimmt man die deutsche Übersetzung des hier gemeinten substantivierten englischen Begriffs *"[to port](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/port--5)",* so muss man die Präposition *"nach"* nehmen, denn man trägt die Software von *"hier **nach** dort"*.

Auch wenn man *"Portierung"* analog dem dafür bereits etablierten Pendant *"[Migration](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Migration)"* betrachtet, kann man durchaus *"von … **nach** … "* wandern, denn auch hier bestimmt der Ort die Handlung.

---

### in

Man findet auch die Migration/Portierung einer Computersprache **in** eine andere, offenbar weil man ja im weitesten Sinne eine Übersetzung vornimmt.

---

### auf

Man kann durchaus auch von einem Betriebssystem **auf** ein anderes migrieren/portieren, da auch hier der Ortswechsel bestimmend für die Präposition ist.

---

### zu

Weniger gebräuchlich ist die Variante mit *"zu"*, wohl weil die Präposition in der Bedeutung *"tragen"* den örtlichen Wechsel nicht so gut abbildet, auch wenn man natürlich Daten von einem System *"zu"* einem anderen (über)tragen kann.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Der Hinweis, dass es noch keine verbindlichen Regeln gibt ist sehr hilfreich.

Answer (score 7):

- *Portierung von … auf* würde ich für eine Portierung zwischen Systemen oder Hardware-Architekturen verwenden, d. h. von einer Plattform auf eine andere.
  "*Portierung von Windows auf Linux*" oder "*Portierung von 32 auf 64 bit*"
- *Portierung von … nach* würde ich für Portierungen zwischen Programmiersprachen und Bibliotheken verwenden.
  "*Portierung von Matlab nach C++ mit QT*" oder "*Portierung von WX nach QT*".
- *Portierung von … zu* bleibt dann für Fälle, in denen nicht das ganze Programm, sondern nur eine Funktion oder Zusätze und Oberflächen geändert werden. Normalerweise sind die anderen beiden Versionen oder eine Formulierung ohne "*Portierung*" jedoch besser.
  "*Portierung der Benutzeroberflächen von Text zu GUI.*" oder evtl. "*Portierung von HTTP zu FTP Unterstützung*"

Comment: Durchaus würde ich jedoch auch sagen *Portierung von Windows nach MacOS*.